# how to use Fancybox 'title' as href?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'm using Fancybox plugin. (http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/)

there is an option to add "title" to each 'a' tag added and this add the title content below the image when user open it.

```
 <a class="fancybox" rel="gallery2" href="img/img.jpg"  title="type here the text that should be under the image">
                    <img src="img/LogosC_11.png" />
 </a>
```

Is there a way to setup so part of the title will be clickable?

attach is an example of what I need.

[image]

Comment: from link you provide: http://jsfiddle.net/cWNw9/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by adding the title to the `<a>` in jquery.

http://jsfiddle.net/cWNw9/822/

```
$('a').attr('title','<a href="/">go home fancybox</a>, you\'re drunk.');
```

rather than hacking the title into the html itself.